# Wamp Server 2.2.21 not showing local files

Tags: wampserver

Wamp Server 2.2.21 has suddenly stopped working with local files. I.E. when I make any changes in html or css files, localhost is not showing that until I upload that files on server. Even images are not showing until I upload that images on server.

Comment: make sure you have linked all your css js and images via local url and not server path, I suspect you are using server path to connect ur imgs etc

Comment: No.. no... I am not using server paths..... but I have to upload edited files at first... then i can check the changes on localhost

Comment: Then my guess is that you are not using localhost, you are actually looking at the live site

Comment: What have you changed recently

Comment: nothing.. i am also surprised. i am using php and mysqli. localhost 2.2.21. local files (even they are .css or .js) html files are not working well. when i upload these files all are good

Comment: Is it a simple browser cache issue refresh cache `CTRL+F5`

Comment: One more thing, I forgot to say <hr />about .css files... if I use inline css, this is working good. but if i change .css file, i have to upload at first

Comment: after all the solution is here:  this is all about a tag, name <base>. I added a base tag in head section, like : <base mydomain.com />. when i remove this tag, all local files are working well........